# How to use a button's attribute in an if statement (Tkinter)

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, button

I can't find anything online for this. I have made a button which has an image on it. The button changes its image every time you click on it. The problem is that I want to use the image in an if statement. What I mean is:

```
if (photobutton's' attribute "image") == photo2:
   code goes here
```

I tried to use hasattr(), but I don't think I can make that work. By the way, the example looks kind of wonky, but that is because I am trying to write in proper English. They are not meant to be strings, I understand that.

Comment: Retrieving a configuration option of a button `B` would be written `B['image']` or `B.cget('image')`.  Note that you need to compare against `str(photo2)`, since the button just saves the name of the image, rather than the image object itself.

Comment: it's more efficient to make a stringvar or global variable holding the image name and change every time the image change

Comment: Can I ask why my answer was unaccepted? Is there anything I can help explain, or something you need me to fix?

Comment: Sorry, that was a misclick!

Comment: Ha, no worries! It happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve this (or any other configuration) with `cget()`

```
if photobutton.cget('image') == str(photo2):
    ...
```